# Getting email Notification files count in result true - PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Need to send mail if outcome result is true but my code getting mail true or false

can we have it to alert us if true

.............................................

```
here is the script sending email.
```

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Infra\ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count} > c:\temp\result.txt

$Output = "D:\Infra\*"

Get-ChildItem D:\Infra\ | select name, lastwritetime, creationTime > c:\temp\file_date_time.txt
Get-date > c:\temp\server_time.txt

((Get-ChildItem $Output | Measure-Object).Count -gt 10)


$attachments = @(
    "c:\temp\result.txt"
    "c:\temp\file_date_time.txt"
    "c:\temp\server_time.txt"
)


$mailArgs = @{
    From =          ""
    To =            ""
    Subject =       ""
    Body =          ""
    Attachments =   $attachments
    SmtpServer =    ""
    Port =          25
    UseSSL =        $true
}
Send-MailMessage @mailArgs
```

Comment: You are getting True/False because of the greater sign (really redirecting output to a file).  Add parenthesis to code to fix issue.  Better to use Out-File.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0):

Your script executes the mail section wether the object count is greater than 10 or not, because it lacks evaluation.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Infra\ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count} > 
c:\temp\result.txt

$Output = "D:\Infra\*"

Get-ChildItem D:\Infra\ | select name, lastwritetime, creationTime > 
c:\temp\file_date_time.txt
Get-date > c:\temp\server_time.txt

#Assign to a variable so you can evaluate value in further steps (If True/false)
$CheckCount = ((Get-ChildItem $Output | Measure-Object).Count -gt 10)

#If CheckCount evaluates to $true, execute the mail section
if($CheckCount){

     $attachments = @(
       "c:\temp\result.txt"
       "c:\temp\file_date_time.txt"
       "c:\temp\server_time.txt"
     )


     $mailArgs = @{
        From =          ""
        To =            ""
        Subject =       ""
        Body =          ""
        Attachments =   $attachments
        SmtpServer =    ""
        Port =          25
        UseSSL =        $true
    }

Send-MailMessage @mailArgs
}
```